# C Preprocessor Macros - conditionals based upon argument concatenation

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I need help with macros, please!

Suppose I’ve got the following constants defined

```
#define foo_tacos_tuesday    1
#define foo_tacos            1
#define foo_nachos_wednesday 2
#define foo_nachos           3
```

I’d like to write a macro that does the following

```
#define MyFancyMacro( arg1, arg2 )                     \
     #if ( foo_ ## arg1 ## _ ## arg2 != foo_ ## arg1 ) \
         foo_ ## arg1 ## _ ## arg2, foo_ ## arg1,
```

So I can set up a mapping table that only maps the mismatching values:

```
static const int mappingTable[] =
    {
         MyFancyMacro(tacos, tuesday)
         MyFancyMacro(nachos, wednesday)
    };
```

In the end the mappingTable should just be two ints in length, containing 2 and 3.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The answers are both bletcherous... rethink your approach. You don't give enough context, but it sure looks like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expand a C preprocessor macro into a preprocessor statement. However, you can use file inclusion to achieve a work-around.

Imagine that you have a header file called `m.h` that has the following contents:

```
#ifndef MY_FANCY_HEADER
#define XFOO2(arg1, arg2) foo_ ## arg1 ## _ ## arg2
#define FOO2(arg1, arg2) XFOO2(arg1, arg2)
#define XFOO(arg1) foo_ ## arg1
#define FOO(arg1) XFOO(arg1)
#endif

#define FOO_ARG1_ARG2 FOO2(ARG1, ARG2)
#define FOO_ARG1 FOO(ARG1)

#if FOO_ARG1_ARG2 != FOO_ARG1
    FOO_ARG1_ARG2, FOO_ARG1,
#endif

#undef ARG1
#undef ARG2
#undef FOO_ARG1_ARG2
#undef FOO_ARG1
```

Then, in your source file, you can do something like this:

```
static const int mappingTable[] = {
    #define ARG1 tacos
    #define ARG2 tuesday
    #include "m.h"

    #define ARG1 nachos
    #define ARG2 wednesday
    #include "m.h"
};
```

I admit it is not ideal, but since you cannot expand a macro into a preprocessor statement, I believe this is the only way to do it with the standard C preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an advanced macro library like [Order-PP](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Order), although the downside with that is a huge amount of included stuff, potentially slow compile times, and questionable portability*.

A function to do what you ask might look something like this:

```
#include <order/interpreter.h>

// defining functions is a bit long-winded
#define ORDER_PP_DEF_8fancy ORDER_PP_FN( \
  8fn(8L, 8R, \
      8if( 8equal(8L, 8R), \
           8print(8space), \
           8print(8L 8comma 8R 8comma) ) ) )

// testing this
ORDER_PP (  // (execute Order code)
  8fancy(1, 1)   //should do nothing
)
ORDER_PP (
  8fancy(2, 3)   //should show 2,3,
)

// wrap up in a conventional C macro
#define MyFancyMacro(arg1, arg2) ORDER_PP( \
    8fancy( foo_ ## arg1 ## _ ## arg2, foo_ ## arg1 ) \
)

// test the full version
#define foo_tacos_tuesday    1
#define foo_tacos            1
#define foo_nachos_wednesday 2
#define foo_nachos           3
static const int mappingTable[] =
{
     MyFancyMacro(tacos, tuesday)    //nothing
     MyFancyMacro(nachos, wednesday) //2,3,
};
```

This is pretty fragile though - it will only work with integers and will barf up an incomprehensible error message if you try to compare something else. Even that requires quite a lot of macro magic behind the scenes to enable something like `==` (it basically has an extremely large number of preset macros like `EQUAL_1_1` returning 1 and `EQUAL_1_0` returning 0). A limitation of the Order language also means you need to use a weird format for integers larger than 99.

(`if` itself is very easy to define as a macro and can be done with only four preprocessor definitions - it's the integer comparison which generates a boolean that's the complex part, since you have to completely reimplement *arithmetic itself* using nothing but token substitution.)

<sub>* Order is standard-compliant, it's most compilers that aren't.</sub>

---

I'd also caution against designing anything with macros that return a trailing comma - that's highly likely to confuse other people (or even you, when you forget), because "syntax in" stops matching up with "syntax out". In fact given that this problem *looks* like building an array and then filtering values out, why not do that for real at runtime during program initialization?